# What is a word for someone who follows out of fear?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in the title, what is a word for someone who follows some person, concept, or idea out of fear of what will happen if they don't follow?

For example, a person who follows some god or religion out of fear of what will happen if they don't.

I'd love a "religious" word ala zealot, fanatic, devout, etc.

Comment: A sheep? A coward? intimidated? submissive? We need more context.

Comment: Added a little more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not exactly fear-specific, but you might call such a person a ***thrall.***

> ### thrall
>
> noun
>
> [. . .]
>
> 2. a person who is morally or mentally enslaved by some power, influence, or the like
>
> [. . .]
>
> *The younger they are, the easier to brainwash and keep in **thrall** by sheer terror.*
>
> <sub>Source: [dictionary.com definitions for “thrall”](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thrall)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ***reverent***.

> When you have great awe and respect for someone or something, and you show it by respectfully worshiping that person, thing, deity, or musical group, you are being reverent.
>
> http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/reverent

*Reverence* is often used in religious contexts and it can be a feeling of *awe*. Thus, you can consider *in awe of (someone or something).*

> *awe* *(n)* an overwhelming feeling of reverence, admiration, fear, etc., produced by that which is grand, sublime, extremely powerful, or the like:
>
> *in awe of God; in awe of great political figures.*
>
> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/awe

Comment: I really like "reverent", but I'm looking for a word with a little more "terror" in it.

Comment: @oconnor0: How about "fear-mongered" or "intimidated" ?